# setting xmpp chat server of jquery mobile based web app

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, xmpp, tomcat6, mobile-website

I am presently working on jquery mobile web app, I want to implement the chat feature in that mobile web app. I have XMPP chat server running in my server along with the SOAP services in the tomcat6 server, all I have to do is that I need to call the service which initites the XMPP chat in jquery mobile web app, but how do I do it.

Please help me.

Comment: *all I have to do is that I need to call the service* what service is this? Second question: what kind of XMPP server are you using? I assume that you have this chat working already on desktop computer - is it not working on mobile web app. Third question that pops to my mind - what do you mean by *mobile web app* - native mobile application, or simply a webpage designed with mobile devices in mind?

Comment: I have xml based soap services running. I have installed xmpp chat openfire server, yes its working fine, with android app.

Comment: You didn't mention a technology used to interface javascript with XMPP or you are missing one. How exactly is the website supposed to access xmpp in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Parvesh said, you can use Strophe for this application, but If you want to save the hassle of parsing and sending XML from mobile app you can do it using some php based XMPP framework like [Jaxl](http://jaxl.net/). Also I would suggest you to use ejabberd server because it is in active development and you can find many different modules for your need http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use Strophe inside your webapp http://strophe.im/ , strophe works well with Openfire Server